# Selective dropping of Indexes

Tags: indexing, basex

Can I selectively drop existing indexes using `db:optimize()`?

As far as I see from the docs, its only possible to completely drop indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, one has to call `db:optimize()` with all the selective paths that should remain. Simple in idea but .. bad in API impl. One needs to write helpers on his own.